# Opening py-files with idle after moving them from Desktop

Tags: python-3.x, directory, python-idle

I wrote my first simple programs in Python 3, and after i accumulated a few ones, I created a new folder to put them in there instead of having them on the desktop.

Now I cannot open them with IDLE unless I move them back to the desktop. What do I have to do in order to edit them at their new location?

Answer (score 0):

Start `IDLE` and then open each of them from the menu:

```
Files | Open...
```

and you will have opportunity to navigate for them in their new folder.

(Next time after it they will be also in the

```
Files | Recent Files
```

sub-menu - more convenient way than browsing folders to find them again.)

Comment: this works, but it's not 100% a solution. i would like to open per 'edit with idle' in the windows explorer from where i put the files to. thanks anyways. better this way, then having to place them on desktop each time.

Comment: I tried to move my `*.py` files to different disks, to different folder, to folder with spaces and accented letters in their names, to deeply nested folders and I'm still able to open them with your manner ("edit with idle"). Something is bad - I guess (from my own experience) on your part.